# How to query rows and grouping them by a foreign key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I created a table `EmployeeSchedule` with the following columns:

```
EmployeeScheduleID bigint
ScheduleTypeID  int
ScheduleDate date
EmployeeIDNumber nvarchar
```

I'm joining it with 2 other tables, `Employees` and `Schedule Library`.

`Employees` table (won't include all the columns):

```
EmployeeIDNumber nvarchar
Firstname nvarchar
MiddleInitial nvarchar
Lastname nvarchar
NameSuffix nvarchar
SectionCode nvarchar
...
```

Schedule Library table:

```
ScheduleTypeID bigint
ScheduleTypeDescription nvarchar
ScheduleTypeCode nchar
```

My query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    es.ScheduleDate,
    sl.ScheduleTypeDescription,
    e.EmployeeIDNumber,
    e.Lastname,
    e.Firstname,
    e.MiddleInitial,
    e.NameSuffix,
    sl.ScheduleTypeCode
FROM
    WebEmployeeSchedule es
LEFT JOIN 
    Employee e ON es.EmployeeIDNumber = e.EmployeeIDNumber
LEFT JOIN 
    ScheduleLibrary sl ON es.ScheduleTypeID = sl.ScheduleTypeID
WHERE
    e.SectionCode = 'Sect12'
    AND YEAR(es.ScheduleDate) = 2021
    AND Month(es.ScheduleDate) = 5
```

It would output this:

| ScheduleDate | ScheduleTypeDescription | EmployeeIDNumber | Lastname | Firstname | MiddleInitial | NameSuffix | ScheduleTypeCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 | 8:00AM - 5:00PM | 1234578 | lastname1 | firstname1 | mi1 |  | 123 |
| 2021-05-02 | 8:00AM - 1:00PM | 1234578 | lastname1 | firstname1 | mi1 |  | 45 |
| 2021-05-01 | 8:00AM - 11:00AM | 7894561 | lastname2 | firstname2 | mi2 |  | 45 |
| 2021-05-02 | 9:00AM - 3:00PM | 7894561 | lastname2 | firstname2 | mi2 |  | 452 |

How can I make it output something like this?

| EmployeeIDNumber | ScheduleDate1 | ScheduleType1 | ScheduleDate2 | ScheduleType2 | So on... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234578 | 05-1-2021 | 123 | 05-2-2021 | 45 | ... |
| 7894561 | 05-1-2021 | 723 | 05-2-2021 | 452 | ... |

Comment: What is wrong with the query that you posted ? What is not working ?

Comment: @Squirrel There's nothing wrong it, I just want it to display it in another way like my example above.

Comment: @noobie_dev42069 you need to pivot but in your case you need to pivot using dynamic sql

Comment: You didn't provide sufficient information for us to help you. Your query involved 3 tables and you only briefly show us one of them. We also need to see some sample data, current output and expected output and also describe any necessary logic involved. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Squirrel My apologies, I added what you said